# Javascript adding textarea size

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a form that has a textarea and includes a couple of buttons 1 will add an additional textarea and the other will remove a textarea 1 at a time unless it’s the last one. It works except that I want the size of each textarea to be the same as the original one but I just can’t seem to figure out what I’m doing wrong.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>CPO Exit Form</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "Styles/Site2.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
    if(counter>9){
      alert("Only 9 areas can be added to the form.");
      return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>'+ counter + ' : </label><textarea style"width: 700px; height: 56px" max="255"></textarea>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

    counter++;
     });
       $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(counter==2){
         alert("This is the last area it cannot be removed from the form.");
         return false;
       }   

    counter--;
      $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });
   });
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="total">
   <fieldset><legend>Action Items:</legend>
    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
     <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <label> 1 : </label><textarea style="width: 700px; height: 56px" max="255"></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>
  <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out that shouldn't have been there, I'm not even sure where I got that syntax from. I've replaced it with this <textarea style"width: 760px; height: 56px" rows="5" style="width: 764px"> and it's now working.

Comment: I think that there is the error of syntax because your calling two times width in the style.
And Why you don't click on the setting for my answer.
Please because I need the point.

Comment: I would love to give you a point if you could tell me how to do that, this was my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your change this sentence

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>'+ counter + ' : </label><textarea style"width: 700px; height: 56px" max="255"></textarea>')
```

After...

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>'+ counter + ' : </label><textarea style"width: 760px; height: 56px" rows="5" style="width: 764px">')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tiny bug but you are missing an `=` after your `style` attribute in your JavaScript. ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLUGb/))

Change this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>'+ counter + ' : </label><textarea style"width: 700px; height: 56px" max="255"></textarea>');
```

To this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>'+ counter + ' : </label><textarea style="width: 700px; height: 56px" max="255"></textarea>');
```

An even cleaner approach is to use CSS to set the style of your `<textarea>` elements like so:

```
textarea.Wide {
  width: 700px;
  height: 56px
}
```

Then you can change your HTML (and JavaScript) to this:

```
<textarea class="Wide" max="255"></textarea>
```